# Doing it with "done" (slang specific?)

Tags: grammar, slang

Reggae/crossover band Skindred:

"You done dead already..."

Naturally, when I heard it first, I thought this was specific exclusively to Jamaican slang, but today I tripped over:

Lynyrd Skynyrd (Cajun?!):

"Twenty years of rotgut whiskey -
Done killed the poor man dead."

Not even the same grammar abuse, methinks. OK, it's a bit vague a question, but which are the rules (surely they exist, exactly as for "standard" grammar) for these slang constructions with "done" (and are there really more than one)?

Comment: I believe this is the *perfective done*: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/perfective-done

Comment: Obligatory scolding: this isn't an abuse of language and it's not slang.  It's dialect.

Comment: BTW, there is nothing particularly Cajun about Lynyrd Skynyrd (or the perfective done) except that they made reference to Cajun people and places often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @stangdon for pointing to the right answer.

Both uses you highlighted are examples are the [perfective done](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/perfective-done). To quote from the [Yale Grammatical Diversity Project](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/perfective-done):

> The use of done expresses that the action or state being described by
> the clause has come to an end (Green 2002). It may also convey an
> attitude of surprise or shock on the part of the speaker (Harris, in
> progress).
>
> Due to its completive meaning, perfective done often appears with
> eventive verbs, which have a natural endpoint. However, in certain
> contexts, perfective done can occur with stative verbs, which do not
> have natural endpoints.

In essence, the perfective done emphasizes the state of something. Not particularly helpful, but read through the Yale article to really get a sense of the diverse ways it's used.

Comment: You did it :-) Hadn't expected it to be so "orthodox" that it has a name.